# How to use the function logarithm in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a command `log(0.25)` but Calculator output is `-0.6` and Perl output is `-1.3`.

Why and how to use it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your calculator is doing base 10 logarithm, perl's `log` function is natural logarithm (base *e*). The perl `log` documentation shows how to get base 10 log, using high school algebra:

```
sub log10 {
    my $n = shift;
    return log($n)/log(10);
}
```

Comment: If it's good enough for the perl documentation, it's good enough for me.

Comment: @devnull You give -1 because someone suggested a working and easy solution? Just because you deem it less than optimal? And despite it being part of the very documentation the question is about?

Comment: @DeVadder I've reversed the vote.  That said, the answer seemed more than _weird_ given [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091074/how-to-use-the-funtion-logarit-in-perl/20091175?noredirect=1#comment29933236_20091074).